# Python-Slugify not working with google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I wanted to import `python-slugify`, since I wanted to create a permalink for my `BlogPost` class, where you take in the title as a parameter for slugify.

Now the problem here is that with these settings:

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe
  version: latest
- name: python-slugify
  version: latest
```

But I get this error:

```
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: the library "python-slugify" is not supported
```

Is there a work-around for this problem?

Comment: It looks like `python-slugify` is pure Python ( https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify ). This means that you can include it's source code in the files you upload to GAE. Once you do that you can simply `import` it.

Comment: Specifying the libraries to include only works for modules managed by the GAE team.

Comment: @bernie: Sorry man, doesn't work, `python-slugify` has dependencies.

Comment: So copy over the dependencies as well. Think about what is going on in appengine. How do you expect third party code to be available on appengine unless you deploy it with your code as well.

Comment: I did, even those have have dependencies, so I working on a work-around.

Comment: so you need to resolve all of the dependencies.  One of the best ways of doing this.  Set up a virtualenv with --no-site-packages.  Then use <virtualenv dir>/bin/easy_install somepackage   it will install all of the it and the dependencies in <virtualenv dir>/lib/python/site-packages. You then copy or link all of these into your project.  (Just make sure everything has pure python implementations)

Comment: @TimHoffman: Thanks for that man. I am working with a virtualevn right now, but there are a lot of other packages installed, so I will have to try and create a new one again. But thanks, this is one good way to work-around the problem.